# Inverse functions from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the definition of a manifold, how do we define the inverse of the coordinate patch, or, more generally, of this kind of bijective functions?$$f:\mathbb{R}^k\to \mathbb{R}^n$$

It suffices to take as example any function of the form $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$. What do we mean by $f^{-1}$?

Comment: If function $f$ is bijective, then $f^{-1}(x)$ is the unique $y$ such that $f(y)=x$. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's meant without more context, but given a map $f: U \to V$ and a value $v \in V$, we sometimes write $f^{-1}(v)$ to denote the preimage $f^{-1}(\{v\})$ of $\{v\}$ under $f$, that is, the set $\{u \in U : f(u) = v\}$.